# Faster alternative to nested loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I have written the below function, which contains a nested loop. In short, it calculates differences in emissions between i (28) pairs alternative technologies for j (48) countries. For a single combination and a single country, it takes 0.32 sec, which should give a total time of 0.32*28*48 = around 7 min. The function actually takes about 50 min, which makes me think there may be some unnecessary computing going on. Is a nested loop the most efficient approach here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
alt.comb.p <- function(Fmat){

    y.empty = matrix(data = 0,ncol = 2,nrow = nrow(FD)-1)
    row.names(y.empty) <- paste(FD$V1[2:nrow(FD)],FD$V2[2:nrow(FD)],sep = " ")
    country.list = unique(FD$V1)

for (j in 1:length(country.list)){ # for every country

for (i in 1:ncol(alt.comb)){ # for every possible combination

  # the final demand of the first item of the combination is calculated
  first = alt.comb[,i][1] 
  first.name = row.names(Eprice.Exio)[first]
  loc1 = grep(pattern = first.name,x = row.names(y.empty))
  country.first = substr(x = row.names(y.empty)[loc1[j]],start = 0,stop = 2) 
  y.empty[,1][loc1[j]] <- Eprice.Exio[first.name,country.first] 

  # the final demand of the second item of the combination is calculated
  second = alt.comb[,i][2] 
  second.name = row.names(Eprice.Exio)[second]
  loc2 = grep(pattern = second.name,x = row.names(y.empty))
  country.second = substr(x = row.names(y.empty)[loc2[j]],start = 0,stop = 2) 
  y.empty[,2][loc2[j]] <- Eprice.Exio[second.name,country.second] 

  # calculates the difference between the total pressures from item 1 and item 2
  r.1 = sum(Fmat%*%as.vector(y.empty[,1]))
  r.2 = sum(Fmat%*%as.vector(y.empty[,2]))
  r.dif = r.1-r.2 # negative means alternative 1 is better
  alt.comb[2+j,i] <- r.dif
  row.names(alt.comb)[2+j] <- country.first

  y.empty = matrix(data = 0,ncol = 2,nrow = nrow(FD)-1)
  row.names(y.empty) <- paste(FD$V1[2:nrow(FD)],FD$V2[2:nrow(FD)],sep = " ")

}

  }
  return(alt.comb)

 }
```

Edit:

A simplified example would be:

```
Fmat = matrix(data = runif(1:9600), ncol=9600, nrow=9600)    
alt.comb.p <- function(Fmat){

  y.empty = matrix(data = 0,ncol = 2,nrow = 9600)
  country.list = runif(n = 10)

  alt.comb = matrix(data=0,ncol=5,nrow=10)

  for (j in 1:10){ # for every country

for (i in 1:5){ # for every possible combination

  y.empty[50,1] <- runif(1)
  y.empty[60,2] <- runif(1)

  # calculates the difference between the total pressures from item 1 and item 2
  r.1 = sum(Fmat%*%as.vector(y.empty[,1]))
  r.2 = sum(Fmat%*%as.vector(y.empty[,2]))
  r.dif = r.1-r.2 # negative means alternative 1 is better
  alt.comb[j,i] <- r.dif

  y.empty = matrix(data = 0,ncol = 2,nrow = 9600)


}

}
 return(alt.comb)

}
```

Comment: Ooh, nesting an `i` loop *inside* a `j` loop, you rebel! But in seriousness, can you share with `dput()` or via simulation some *small* sample data to try this on?

Comment: And is `Fmat` the same as `FD`? You seem to reference `FD` a lot, but it's not a function argument so your function is just hoping it's hanging around in the global environment?

Comment: @Gregor thanks for the reply. So I have built a simpler example as suggested and it seems the nested loop is much faster than simply multiplying the time for the first iteration. That makes me think that it is not the nested loop that is slowing down the function as I initially thought. I will try putting variables outside the function and see what happens...

Comment: FD is indeed in the global environment

Comment: "*I will try putting variables outside the function and see what happens*" Why? That seems like making your function more fragile and less generalizable. Again, please **share** with `dput()` or via simulation your small example. It's very difficult to work on the problem (or even really understand what your loop is doing) without any test data.

Comment: Instead of looping, have you tried `expand.grid(technology = c('foo', 'bar'), country = c('Aruba', 'Bonaire', 'Curacao')`? Then merge whatever variables are needed for you calculation, and then add columns for each calculated field. (It's a little hard to tell what you're actually trying to calculate without example data, so this may not work -- but it would certainly be faster than nested for-loops.)

Comment: @Gregor, see example as edit. In this, the first iteration takes 1.32 sec, while the whole loop takes 14.96 sec. I think this may mean that some temporary objects stored within the actual function become increasingly large and consume memory, thus slowing the calculation each iteration.

Comment: Can't run your code without `FD`. Can't help if I can't run your code.